# Display is lost when turned off (standby), desktop is automatically adjusted randomly

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xfce, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I have two displays connected via HDMI and whenever I turn one off (power button/standby), the system thinks that the monitor was disconnected entirely and automatically reconfigures the desktop, moves all open programs to the active display and adjusts the background accordingly. So far, this is okay.

However, when I turn the monitor back on, chaos ensues. Both displays switch off and back on for a while and may overlap or get mirrored seemingly at random.

Since I have a specific physical setup (secondary monitor positioned slightly to the upper right of the main one), I always have to manually restore the display positioning after the system has lost it.

This is happening on a Ryzen 3400G on Xfce 4.14.

Previously, I have used this exact same installation and monitor setup in another system with an AMD Firepro GPU without issues, hence I suppose that the driver (amdgpu instead of radeon) is the culprit. Although one monitor was connected via DVI, which I can not replicate anymore now.

Is there any way to make the system/driver behave more like the radeon one so that it "doesn't care" if a display is disconnected?